# $stateChangeStart run before getting data from Rest API

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

I'm tried to do user login authentication, I've made a service named `AuthService` with a method `isAuthenticated` in which I make a call to API to cross check the user is logged in or not (Also I'll user the user role in it later), and then I call this service in `$rootScope.$on` but its not wait until my service get data from API, Here is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.
        state('/', {
            url: "/",
            views: {
                header: {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/common/header.html',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                },
                content: {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                }
            },
            title: 'Dashboard',
            authenticate: true
        })

        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            views: {
                content: {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                }
            },
            title: 'Login',
            authenticate: false
        })        

        .state('dashboard', {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            url: "/dashboard",
            views: {
                header: {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/common/header.html',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                },
                content: {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                }
            },
            authenticate: true
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        //check browser support
        if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                 enabled: true,
                 requireBase: false
            });
        }
  }])
 .run(function ($rootScope, $location, $state, Data, AuthService) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $rootScope.title = toState.title;
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            var userInfo = AuthService.isAuthenticated();
            if (toState.authenticate && !AuthService.isAuthenticated()){
                  // User isn’t authenticated
                  $state.transitionTo("login");
                  event.preventDefault();
            } else {
               alert('here I am ='+$rootScope.authenticated);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is my service

```
app.factory('AuthService', function ($http, Data, $rootScope) {
  var authService = {};

  authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
    Data.get('index.php/api/authentication/is_login').then(function (results) {
        if (results.uid) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
            $rootScope.uid = results.uid;
            $rootScope.name = results.name;
            $rootScope.email = results.email;
            return results.uid;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
  }
  return authService;
});
```

Tried lot of things but no luck so far, Please suggest a best way to do it, I've tried the resolve method in ui-routes but didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you tagged this question with `php` ?

Comment: As I am using codeigniter for rest API

Answer (score 0):

The implementation that you currently have will not work because the `Data.get()` function returns a `Promise`, and is therefore asynchronous. Because of this, the route change will go ahead without waiting until your authentication service has returned any value.

To resolve your issue, you should handle this asynchronous logic in a particular way:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $state, Data, AuthService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    /**
     * If the user is heading towards a state that requires
     * authentication, assume that they are not authenticated,
     * and stop them! Otherwise, let them through...
     */
    if (toState.authenticate) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (toState.name !== fromState.name) {
        // Now check whether or not they are authenticated
        AuthService.isAuthenticated().then(function () {
          // Yes! They're authenticated, continue
          $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
        }, function () {
          // Nope, this user cannot view this page
          alert('You cannot view this page!');
        });
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

> **Edit:** I have added a check statement `toState.name !== fromState.name` to break any redirect loops that may then cause endless calls to the authentication service. This was in response to a comment made by the original poster of the issue.

> The trick is to prevent the route transition, *by default*. You are then able to perform as much asynchronous logic as you wish before the user is permitted to move any further on.
>
> I would recommend adding a spinner, or a loading window, to alert the user to the fact that you are performing this authentication check. It may also be wise to prevent any further user actions on the page, but that's entirely up to you.

Note that the function `AuthService.isAuthenticated()` now returns a `Promise`, you will have to make a minor change to your authentication service to achieve this. Simply wrap your current logic like this:

```
app.factory('AuthService', function ($http, Data, $rootScope, $q) {
  var authService = {};

  authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
      Data.get('index.php/api/authentication/is_login').then(function (results) {
        if (results.uid) {
          $rootScope.authenticated = true;
          $rootScope.uid = results.uid;
          $rootScope.name = results.name;
          $rootScope.email = results.email;

          // Great, the user is authenticated, resolve the Promise
          resolve(results.uid);
        } else {
          // The user does not appear to be authenticated, reject the Promise
          reject();
        }
      });
    });
  };

  return authService;
});
```

I hope that this resolves your issue, Promises can be a pain, but they can also be a pretty powerful tool. There was a good thread on GitHub discussing a number of potential solutions around this issue that can be found here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1399.

---

- `$q`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Really thanks for your reply man. I've implement it & getting error in my  console TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Have you updated your `AuthService.isAuthenticated()`, so that it returns a `Promise`?

Comment: yes I changed my service, now my http request return user data if user is logged in & a blank object if user is not logged in

Comment: I've fixed the error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined", but another issue is there when http request authenticate any user then it will redirect to $state.go(toState.name, toParams);, its getting in infinite loop to make call http request to validate user.

Comment: You could add a check to confirm that the state is definitely different from the last state by adding a check before calling `AuthService.isAuthenticated()`, I'll update the post.

Comment: getting same issue, fromState & fromParams getting blank object all the time

Comment: Are you causing page refreshes, and therefore causing these issues? For `fromState` and `fromParams` to be undefined "all the time" you must be either accessing the application for the first time, or you are simply using AngularJS incorrectly, it is a single page web application framework designed to be loaded, and then used over a continuous period; not a server side rendered product like PHP based solutions.