# Is there any way to put user authentication with angular-ui-routes instead of $stateChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

I'm new with Angular js & try to make a website with Angular & rest API (codeigniter), but getting stuff with user authentication.

I've tried lot of things to make it happen but no luck so far, I wants to set my routes with `angular-ui-routes` with user authentication with it based on user role.

For now I'm checking the user authentication via a service which calls to rest API every time under the `$stateChangeStart` but as I'm going to add more URL's then its getting panic to put conditions in it.

So I'm looking for a solution in which I can set user authentication & user role under my `ui-routes`.

I'm not sure that this question is asked here before but I didn't get any solid solution for it, Please advice if its possible to do, if so then how can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$stateChangeStart run before getting data from Rest API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045474/statechangestart-run-before-getting-data-from-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `resolve`.

Basically you can do something like this:

```
//You can inject any service here.
//Return a promise to be resolved or an ordinary object
function tryAuth($state, Auth){ 
    return Auth.currentUser() 
            //In this case currentUser() will return a promise containing an instance
            //of the user if it exists or call $http to try to authenticate the user from
            //saved credentials.
            .catch(function(){
             //If the promise rejects for any reason, move to a different state.
             $state.go('login'); //This is just an example
            });
}

$stateProvider
 .state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl 'partials/login.html',
  controller: 'loginCtrl'
 })
 .state('profile', {
  url: '/profile',
  templateUrl: 'partials/profile.html',
  controller: 'profileCtrl',
  resolve: {
   //In the controller you can inject user to recieve the actual user
   user: tryAuth
 }
});
```

This can be refactored in many ways but you get the idea.

Another solution I used in the past is something similar to this:

```
//In config clause
$stateProvider
 .state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl 'partials/login.html',
  controller: 'loginCtrl'
 })
 .state('profile', {
  url: '/profile',
  templateUrl: 'partials/profile.html',
  controller: 'profileCtrl',
  requireLogin: true
});

//In run clause
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log('Moving to state: ' + toState.name + ' from state: ' + fromState.name);
        /* Require users to login to certain sections */
        if (toState.requireLogin && !Auth.currentUser) {
            event.preventDefault();
            Auth.reAuthenticate().then(function () {
                //Complete the transition after authentication
                $state.go(toState, toParams);
            }).catch(function () {
                loginModal().then(function () {
                    //Complete the transition after authentication
                    $state.go(toState, toParams);
                }).catch(function () {
                   //If the state is not abstract
                    if (!fromState.abstract)      
                        //Go back to the state you came from
                        return $state.go(fromState, fromParams); 
                    $state.go('default');
                });
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Should I have to make an another service named Auth? Or its an by default feature of Angular

Comment: `Auth` is your service that is responsible for the authentication of users across your application. It doesn't have to be named `Auth` although it is good practice in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, I used something like that but in my Auth service I make a http request to get current user status in which I got issue that resolve is not wait to load data from http request & all the time I got false & undefind.

Comment: I've also posted a question before here too with some code which I made , You can check it out here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045474/statechangestart-run-before-getting-data-from-rest-api

Comment: Then the first answer is the better choice for you as it will wait for the promise to resolve before moving to that state. I've added a comment in the `resolve` declaration in the first example

Comment: Really thanks for help me Man, let me try to implement your first idea, Can I use user role in it too anyhow?

Comment: You can but this would be bad practice. remember - any code you do is **client-side** meaning an attacker can essentially just change his client code.

Comment: so what's the best & secure way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111126/discussion-between-muli-yulzary-and-nipun-tyagi).

Comment: can you please do one favor, can you please post your Auth service code too in your answer ?